# Query additional data with SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a simple model for a blog system:

```
class Blog(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'blog'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='blog', lazy='dynamic')

class Post(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String())
```

<sub>I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy, so the syntax might look a bit different, the mapping is pretty straight forward though.</sub>

Is it possible to fetch all blogs alongside the post count? Because right now iterating over a list performs an additional query per iteration and that doesn't really scale. It's pretty simple in SQL:

```
SELECT b.*, COUNT(p)
FROM blog b
    JOIN post p ON(b.id = p.blog_id)
GROUP BY b.id;
```

But how is it done in SQLAlchemy? Preferably I'd like to have two options:

- specify at query time
- create a "virtual" property in the model itself to use it always (e.g. Hibernate calls this [formulas](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2785))

I think I'm missing the right terminology because I just couldn't find anything with Google.

Answer (score 0):

See below, the code should answer both of your questions. Answer to the second part uses [Hybrid Extension](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-a-hybrid).

```
class Blog(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'blog'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='blog', lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def num_posts(self):
        # return len(self.posts)  # use if relationship is *not* dynamic
        return self.posts.count()

    @num_posts.expression
    def _num_posts_expression(cls):
        return (db.select([db.func.count(Post.id)])
                .where(Post.post_id == cls.id)
                .label("num_posts")
                )


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Blog.id))
    title = db.Column(db.String())


def test():
    with app.app_context():
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

        def create_test_data():
            blogs = [
                Blog(name="empty",),
                Blog(name="geo",
                     posts=[
                         Post(title='west'),
                         Post(title='east'),
                         Post(title='north'),
                         Post(title='south'),
                     ]),
                Blog(name="food",
                     posts=[
                         Post(title='sour'),
                         Post(title='sweet'),
                     ]),
            ]
            db.session.add_all(blogs)
            db.session.commit()

        create_test_data()


        # simple query
        q = (db.session.query(Blog, db.func.count(Post.id).label("num_posts"))
             .outerjoin(Post, Blog.posts)
             .group_by(Blog.id)
             )
        for b, num_posts in q:
            print(b, num_posts)
        print("-"*80)


        # Using hybrid_attribute
        # num_posts is fetched later
        q = (db.session.query(Blog))
        for b in q:
            print(b)
            print(b.num_posts)
        print("-"*80)

        # num_posts is fetched with the query
        q = (db.session.query(Blog, Blog.num_posts))
        for b in q:
            print(b)
            print(b.num_posts)
        print("-"*80)
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'll try it out in the evening. Do you happen to know if you can assign the count to a property of `Blog` instead of getting a tuple (or whatever) back? I know I can loop myself and do it but maybe SQLAlchemy can do it automatically?

Comment: `# simple query` is the first part of your question. The rest uses `hybrid_property` which is exactly a property on the `Blog` class, as you can see from the code.

Comment: You're right, it works for the hybrid property. But does it also work with the simple query?